# Convert list-of-dicts into tree

Tags: python, list, tree, categories, nested-lists

For two days I try to traverse a list of dicts into a tree.

```
`list_of_dicts = [
{'name':Category1, 'id': '7', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '1'}
{'name':Category3, 'id': '33', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '2'}
{'name':Category5, 'id': '334', 'parent_id': '33', 'level': '3'}
{'name':Category10, 'id': '23', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '2'}
{'name':Category2, 'id': '8', 'parent_id': '8', 'level': '1'}
{'name':Category6, 'id': '24', 'parent_id': '8', 'level': '2'}
]`
```

As informations, we know a category on top level (1), has its own id as its parent_id, children have the id of its parent as parent_id and the level.

In a first step the list need to turn in something like a tree:

```
`traversed_list = [
{'name':Category1, 'id': '7', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '1',      'children':
[
{'name':Category3, 'id': '33', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '2', 'children': [
{'name':Category5, 'id': '334', 'parent_id': '33', 'level': '3', 'children':[]}]}
{'name':Category10, 'id': '23', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '2', 'children':[]}
]}
{'name':Category2, 'id': '8', 'parent_id': '8', 'level': '1', 'children':
[{'name':Category6, 'id': '24', 'parent_id': '8', 'level': '2', 'children':[]}]
}]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
import copy

def treeify(lst):
  tree = [copy.deepcopy(cat) for cat in lst if cat['level'] == '1']
  for el in tree:
    el["children"] = []
  for i in xrange(len(lst)):
    for j in xrange(len(tree)):
      if lst[i]["parent_id"] == tree[j]["id"]:
        tree[j]["children"].append(copy.deepcopy(lst[i]))
  return tree

list_of_dicts = [
  {'name':"Category1", 'id': '7', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '1'},
  {'name':"Category3", 'id': '33', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '2'},
  {'name':"Category5", 'id': '334', 'parent_id': '33', 'level': '3'},
  {'name':"Category10", 'id': '23', 'parent_id': '7', 'level': '2'},
  {'name':"Category2", 'id': '8', 'parent_id': '8', 'level': '1'},
  {'name':"Category6", 'id': '24', 'parent_id': '8', 'level': '2'}
]

tree = treeify(list_of_dicts)
for d in tree:
  print d
```

prints

```
{'id': '7', 'parent_id': '7', 'children': [{'id': '7', 'parent_id': '7', 'name': 'Category1', 'level': '1'}, {'id': '33', 'parent_id': '7', 'name': 'Category3', 'level': '2'}, {'id': '23', 'parent_id': '7', 'name': 'Category10', 'level': '2'}], 'name': 'Category1', 'level': '1'}
{'id': '8', 'parent_id': '8', 'children': [{'id': '8', 'parent_id': '8', 'name': 'Category2', 'level': '1'}, {'id': '24', 'parent_id': '8', 'name': 'Category6', 'level': '2'}], 'name': 'Category2', 'level': '1'}
```

Comment: Hello EvenLisle! I was surprised, so quickly to get an answer! Unfortunally it isnt the expected result, cause children are more than onetime in the tree, but they may not being at first level. But I think it is the right way.

Comment: Instead of `tree = copy.deepcopy(lst)` we could copy only the elements of first level or the elements which have parent_id == id. Could you confirm?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. I apparently didn't read your question closely enough. Your edit suggestion is correct, I've approved it now.